# MongooseModule.forRootAsync - can't resolve depencies

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to use mongoose and dynamically configure the connection by following the same from nestjs.com, but in my case the services that I need to inject to the factory won't be resolved. 
here is the `AppModule`

```
@Injectable()
class Op implements MongooseOptionsFactory {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => EndpointsService))
    private endpointsService: EndpointsService) {
  }

  createMongooseOptions(): MongooseModuleOptions {
    return {
      uri: this.endpointsService.loginMongoDb
    };
  }
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: Op,
      inject: [EndpointsService] // having this doesn't help either
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, UserController],
  providers: [AppService, 
    EndpointsService, // is in the core module, but won't be seen
    UserService]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

pretty simple (ignore the Op name, I'll move it where needed later)

And here is the `EndpointsService`

```
@Injectable()
export class EndpointsService {
  private readonly _loginApi: string;
  private readonly _loginMongoDb: string;

  constructor() {
....
```

but ap won't start, with the error

```
[Nest] 83842   - 03/20/2020, 10:54:26 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[0] [Nest] 83842   - 03/20/2020, 10:54:26 AM   [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +14ms
[0] [Nest] 83842   - 03/20/2020, 10:54:26 AM   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Op (?). Please make sure that the argument EndpointsService at index [0] is available in the MongooseCoreModule context.
[0] 
[0] Potential solutions:
[0] - If EndpointsService is a provider, is it part of the current MongooseCoreModule?
[0] - If EndpointsService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MongooseCoreModule?
[0]   @Module({
[0]     imports: [ /* the Module containing EndpointsService */ ]
[0]   })
[0]  +0ms
```

I also tried to use regular injection without `forwardRef` in the `Op` class, but the result is the same.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To inject a service into an async configuration, that service or provider must be either

1. in the scope of the module via module importing
2. a global service, provided via a global module

In this case, the `EndpointsService` belongs to the `AppModule`, but the `AppModule` is not imported into the `MongooseModule` for configuration (which would be pretty confusing as that's a major circular dependency). What you should do instead is create an `EndpointsModule` that `provides` and `exports` the `EndpointsService` like so:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [EndpointsService],
  exports: [EndpointsService],
})
export class EndpointsModule
```

And now in your `MongooseModule` you can do async configuration like so

```js
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [EndpointsModule],
  useClass: Op,
})
```

Comment: I didn't really want to add a new module, but it looks like without it won't work. Works now with the new module. :)

Comment: I live by the philosophy, "If it's a feature, it needs a module". So far so good with it to be honest